# how use _.mergewith of lodash and customizer function

Tags: node.js, object, merge, lodash

Hi i need merge two object with mergewith in lodash ...

```
object1 = {
    "a": {
        "name": "masoud", "age": 3, "user": "masmas"
    },
    "b" : {
        "name": "milad", "age": 13, "user": "milmil"
    }
}

object2 = {
    "b" : {
        "pythonSkill" : 18 , "HTMLSkill" : 15 
    } , 
    "c" : {
        "phpSkill" : 15 , "CSSSkill" : 16 
    },
    "a" : {
        "javaSkill" : 20 , "reactSkil" : 10 
    } , 
}
```

and finally combined object sample :

```
final = {
    "a": {
        "name": "masoud", "age": 3, "user": "masmas", "persianLanguage": 20, "englishLanguage": 10
    },
    "b" : {
        "name": "milad", "age": 13, "user": "milmil" , "pythonSkill": 18, "HTMLSkill": 15
    }
}
```

Each object does not have a specific number of internal objects and may be different each time .
one time Object1 have a , b , c , .... , m & other time Object1 have m , n , o , c , ...

Object2 similar object1 ...

Different scenarios
1- if Object1 have "a" and object2 have "a" , finally object must have "a" ..
2- if Object1 have not "a" and object2 have "a" , finally object have not "a" ..
3- if Object1 have "a" and object2 have not "a" , finally object have not "a"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about using [_.mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith), this seems to me to be rather difficult but you can use [_.mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapValues) and [_.pickBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pickBy) to achieve the desired result relatively easily

```js
object1 = {
    "a": {
        "name": "masoud", "age": 3, "user": "masmas"
    },
    "b" : {
        "name": "milad", "age": 13, "user": "milmil"
    },
    "d" : {
        "name": "nassim", "age": 32, "user": "nm1"
    }
}

object2 = {
    "b" : {
        "pythonSkill" : 18 , "HTMLSkill" : 15 
    } , 
    "c" : {
        "phpSkill" : 15 , "CSSSkill" : 16 
    },
    "a" : {
        "javaSkill" : 20 , "reactSkil" : 10 
    } , 
}

let final = _.mapValues(_.pickBy(object1, (v,k) => object2[k]), (v, k, o) => { 
    return { ...v, ...object2[k] }
});
console.log(final)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```